# if statement using Zencart order status

Tags: php, if-statement, zen-cart

I am trying to make something appear if the status of the order is "shipped"

I have created the following trying to get it to show only if the status

```
$ship_status = $orders->fields['orders_status_name'];
   if ($ship_status="Shipped")
{
   echo "Shipped Out";
}
```

When I echo `$orders->fields['orders_status_name']` I get

Update 
 
Update 
 
Printing 
 
Deleted 
 
Shipped 
 
Shipped  
Update   
 
Shipped 
 
Shipped 
Shipped  
 
Shipped  
Shipped  
Shipped

so if I was to place that next to the if statement I should get "Shipped Out" next to those that are "Shipped" ... But i get "Shipped Out" next to EVERY one!

So I do not know what to do now! Any help would be GREAT!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing `=` with `==`. 
You want

if ($ship_status=="Shipped")

One equals sign is an assignment.  Two is a comparison.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Oh geeze! Too much time in front of the screen makes you overlook the most obvious solution!